# Some drives not seen

Tags: 11.10, mount, hard-drive

I just updated to Ubuntu 11.10. When I put in a 100mb Zip floppy, it shows in the launcher but I'm only allowed to eject it. I installed Storage Device Manager and it sees the drive but all the files are greyed out. Also, I'm running Ubuntu from a 80Gb IDE harddrive but it cannot see my 500Gb SATA hard disk. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

That's an interesting combination of old bits. I assume it's a USB zip drive? It sounds like the drive was added but was then pushed offline, the media could have failed. Anyhow...

```
sudo apt-get install lsscsi
lsscsi -l
```

What's the state of the zip drive? Is it `state=offline`?

If you look through you logs e.g. `dmesg`, do you see anything related?

My initial impression is that your hardware is failing or that piece of
zip media is defunct. This would be easier to narrow down if you had extra
zip media to try out.

As for the 500G disk. Is it something you could read from before? Do you know
what it filesystem is?